# Error while creating data connection using XML Document in InfoPath

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Referring to this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/01/15/populating-form-data-from-sharepoint-list-views.aspx

I am trying to create an XML Document data connection using a URL but when I enter this URL and click the next button I get the error below:

> The file or folder name `https://contoso.test.net/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={32364DED-7FE3-4276-837C-F2AC62C04B81}&View={804CC528-34B2-4473-89DB-C4E766CACC95}&XMLDATA=TRUE&NOREDIRECT=TRUE` contains characters that are not permitted. Enter different name.

In thing the issue is not with URL but with XML returned by the URL. I tried this URL in browser and get below XML –

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
 xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='30'>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_ID' rs:name='ID' rs:number='1'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='i4' dt:maxLength='4' />
  </s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row ows_ID='1247' />
<z:row ows_ID='1246' />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Comment: It's been resolved, i just try this from different machine. May be InfoPath Designer cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following URL:

```
https://contoso.test.net/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=%7BF8DA6205%2DABF1%2D4D03%2D82CC%2D60F9AD78170B%7D&XMLDATA=TRUE&NOREDIRECT=TRUE
```

Just Encode your URL.

Comment: Not worked by encoding url

Comment: what is you final url?

Comment: So when are you getting the above mentioned error?

Comment: so what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{ & }` from the url and you will be fine. I strip the `{` from the URL see below.

```
 https://contoso.test.net/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=32364DED-7FE3-4276-837C-F2AC62C04B81&View=804CC528-34B2-4473-89DB-C4E766CACC95&XMLDATA=TRUE&NOREDIRECT=TRUE
```

Check below article for the URL Protocol.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms478653(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms478653%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Stripping braces also not worked but it give me below error  We can not connect to https://contoso.test.net/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={32364DED-7FE3-4276-837C-F2AC62C04B81}&View={804CC528-34B2-4473-89DB-C4E766CACC95}&XMLDATA=TRUE&NOREDIRECT=TRUE Please make sure you are using correct web address.

Comment: is it typo, becuase i am still seeing the braces in the url? can you share the URL you are using....from _vti_bin to True.also share the error

Comment: We can not connect to 'https://contoso.test.net/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=A54CB1CB-407C-422A-A023-1D7F32E6F41B&View=0185F65B-EA43-48E0-8633-FE229D9D8CDD&XMLDATA=TRUE&NOREDIRECT=TRUE Please make sure you are using correct web address'